# Eclipse Server view status missing

Tags: eclipse, server

A week or so ago, I opened the server tab to start one of my local Tomcat servers and the status "[Stopped, Synchronized]" was missing. I've tried resetting/changing the Perspective and changing themes (in case the color blended in with the background). I can't find any settings that I may have accidentally changed to hide the status and I'm finding it quite frustrating. I know that I can look at the toolbar to see i the Stop Server button is lit but that's very easy to overlook and doesn't specifically tell me which server is running. Any ideas?

[Picture of my Server tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftqOl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your **Label Decorations** preference page for a disabled **Server State Decorator**.

[image: The Label Decorations preference page.]

Comment: Thanks so much. This was driving me crazy.